# Technological incompetence

Tags: quadratic-reciprocity

I am a high school student going into my junior year.  Earlier this summer, I went to a math camp at Ohio State University, and one of the assignments was to prove quadratic reciprocity.  I was told that one of the proofs involved lattice points, so I tried to find a proof that involved lattice points.  Eventually, I happened upon such a proof, and excitedly showed it to my counselor, who told me that my proof was different from the "conventional" lattice point proof, and that he had never seen my proof before.  I then showed the proof to two professors, neither of whom had ever seen it, and doing some cursory internet research with one of those professors did not yield any identical proofs.  Now, I am trying to figure out whether or not my proof is original ([this site](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/rchrono.html) identifies (but does not give) a whopping 246 different proofs, far more than either professor had ever seen).  I was advised to post my proof on Math Stack Exchange, except I am stuck due to my technological incompetence.  The problem is that my proof requires several diagrams, and I do not know how to type them.  To e-mail the proof to the professor who ran the math camp that I went to, my mom made me draw the diagrams and then scanned them into the document in which I typed the written part of the proof.  By doing that, she created a PDF.  Unfortunately, the PDF is more than 2 MiB (in addition to some weird stuff happening on my Mac), and I cannot upload it here.  In general, I am not good at the use of computers in everyday life.  What should I do?

(For the record, if this requires some sort of TeX-type language, the diagrams in my proof involve coordinate planes, in which some (not all) lattice points have dots (or larger dots if all lattice points have dots), and others have circles around them, and still others have a dot/larger dot and have a circle around that.  In addition, there are lines and labels in these diagrams.)

Thank you.

Comment: You can take a picture of your diagram (using a camera or preferably using your computer's screenshot function) and upload it here.

Comment: Duh.  My family's Mac was doing weird things, but I should see if that works.

Comment: You could get a [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) account and distribute the entire PDF that way. As a new user to MSE, you may need to 'break' the link, if you do choose this route.